# Passing Integer List from Java to Oracle Function

Tags: java, oracle, function, arraylist, types

> I know this may be duplicate question, I checked few solutions related
>   and couldn't proceed ahead.

I have few questions in passing integer list from Java and using it in Oracle function.

1. An operator list is passed to oracle function from Java in this format : '11111, 22222'. 11111 and 22222 are numbers, but passing in single quotes, so that it is passed as one variable. Is there any better way to pass this variable ?

   **Java snippet:**

   ```
   List<Integer> operatorList = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

modifying the operatorList to include single quotes at the beginning and end and passing to function. --> ***not sure if this is right approach***

```
userOrgList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery
            ("SELECT message FROM TABLE (FUNC_GetMessages(**:operatorList**))")
                                    .setParameter("operatorList", inputOperatorList)
                                    .setFetchSize(5000).list();
```

2. In Oracle, as I am expecting this as,

`SELECT Message FROM TABLE (FUNC_GetMessages('11111, 22222'));`

so that, I can remove the quotes and pass the value directly as a parameter to the table.

Type is created to handle this parameter.

**Oracle :**

```
create or replace TYPE OPERATOR_ARRAY_DEL AS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/

create or replace FUNCTION FUNC_GetMessages (
    OperatorList IN VARCHAR2
)   

RETURN T_MSGTABLE AS
vMsg_List       T_MSGTABLE;
v_Operator_List VARCHAR(50);
v_operatorList    VARCHAR(100) :='';
v_operatorFinalList    VARCHAR(100) ;
v_operatorId     VARCHAR(20);
v_operatorFinal OPERATOR_ARRAY_DEL := OPERATOR_ARRAY_DEL();
BEGIN

FOR iOperator IN 
        (SELECT to_number(column_value) as v_operatorId FROM xmltable(OperatorList)) 
        LOOP
        v_operatorList := v_operatorList  ||  iOperator.v_operatorId || ',';

        SELECT SUBSTR(v_operatorList, 1, LENGTH(v_operatorList) - 1) INTO v_operatorFinalList FROM DUAL; 

  END LOOP;   

... some code here
...
....

  SELECT SUBSTR(v_operatorList, 1, LENGTH(v_operatorList) - 1) INTO v_operatorList FROM DUAL;   

    SELECT T_MSGTABLE( message) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO vSMs_List
    FROM 
    (  
        SELECT MESSAGE FROM MESSAGETABLE WHERE OPERATOR IN (v_operatorFinalList);
    );
END;
```

**Func Execution:**

`SELECT Message FROM TABLE (FUNC_GetMessages('11111, 22222'));` `--> Error here : Invalid number`

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "FUNC_GetMessages", line 29
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

I am not sure how to interpret the operatorList and pass to a table to fetch the results.

Expected outcome is multiple rows from the select statement

Any pointers and suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: If this is for Hibernate, you might want to tag it as such as I almost asked why you weren't using a `CallableStatement` until I realized this wasn't JDBC.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any easy way to do this in Hibernate.  If this were JDBC, I'd tell you to create a `java.sql.Array` using a `Connection` object's `createArrayOf` command... something like `java.sql.Array operatorArray = conn.createArrayOf("INTEGER", operatorList.toArray());` which can then be passed to a `PrepareStatement`'s `setArray`.  That is, assuming you actually coded the Stored Function to take a SQL Array.

Comment: @Powerlord, thanks for reminding to tag this under Hibernate. Added other tags but forgot this. :)
I tried passing the input as String and then parse it . I also tried passing as TYPE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably an easier Java way to do this, but you're also overcomplicating things in your function. That `xmltable` query is converting your list into a table that you can iterate over - there's no need to put it back into a varchar2 again.

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNC_GetMessages (
    OperatorList IN VARCHAR2
)   
RETURN T_MSGTABLE AS
  vMsg_List       T_MSGTABLE;
BEGIN 

... some code here
...
....

    SELECT T_MSGTABLE( message) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO vMsg_List
    FROM 
    (  
        SELECT MESSAGE FROM MESSAGETABLE WHERE OPERATOR IN 
          (SELECT to_number(column_value) as opId FROM xmltable(OperatorList));
    );
END;
```

Comment: this worked as expected and you are right that I complicated the data fetching in the DB function.